# R - evd package - declustering for bivariate threshold excess model

Tags: r

Using the evd package in R, we can decluster data when fitting a peak over threshold model using the argument `cmax = True` in our call to `fpot()`.

Is there a way to implement declustering when fitting a bivariate peak over threshold model? The `fbvpot()` function does not seem to take the `cmax` argument.